# Extract elements from a json file in python

Tags: python, json

Using Python, I have the following JSON structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "data": "{'id': '1', 'title': 'title of id 1', 'foo': 'bar', 'fooo': ['bar', 'baar']}"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data": "{'id': '2', 'title': 'title of id 2', 'foo': 'bar', 'fooo': ['bar', 'baar']}"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "data": "{'id': '3', 'title': 'title of id 3', 'foo': 'bar', 'fooo': ['bar', 'baar']}"
    }
]
```

I want to store the first to elements of data inside a new .json like

```
[
{
 1 : 'title of 1',
 2 : 'title of 2',
...
}
]
```

Now, i have tried a lot of things, the most recent ones were:

```
Index = []
for x in checklists:
    item = {"id": x}
    Index.append(x)
return Index
```

Or

```
Index = []
for x in checklists:
    x = json.dumps(x)
    Index.append(x.id)
return Index
```

But every time i try to execure it, i receive the same error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
> ```

Which leads my to my question. Is my json formated in a wrong way? Or are my functions wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ast` module.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
index_list = []
for x in checklists:
    val = ast.literal_eval(x["data"])
    index_list.append({x['id']: val["title"]})
return index_list
```

**Output:**

```
[{1: 'title of id 1'}, {2: 'title of id 2'}, {3: 'title of id 3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Index.append(x.id)` to `Index.append(x['id'])`

This is because id is not an attribute of your JSON.

Comment: Both answers return a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error

Answer (score 0):

Without ast it will take some work to get this done. Problem is that the data block is one string (which is valid json) but not what you want.

What you want is the data in data to be formatted comme ca:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {"id": "1", "title": "title of id 1", "foo": "bar"}
}
```

Now when you loop over each data block (where json_array is your complete json) with:

```
for json_block in json_array:
    temp = json_block['data']
    title = (temp['title'])
```

or:

```
for json_block in json_array:
    title= json_block['data']['title']
```

You can now easily add each title to a new array:

```
    index_list.append({'id': title})
```

The whole method would look like:

```
def create_new_json():
    index_list = []
    for json_block in json_array:
        index_list.append({json_block ['id']: json_block ['data']['title']})
```